# How can I remove sequential duplicates using multiple conditions while retaining pairs of rows?

Tags: python, pandas

As part of cleaning a large dataset, I am removing sequential duplicates (with thanks to the answer to this question: [How can I drop consecutive duplicate rows in one column based on condition/grouping from another column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428611/how-can-i-drop-consecutive-duplicate-rows-in-one-column-based-on-condition-group)).

Further exploring has found that a relative row (always one above) is important so needs to be kept and also considered within the de-duplication process (potential an IF  then retain process).

An example of my dataset is below (normally 100k + rows with various additional columns:

(* marks duplicates to be removed)

```
zone | datetime         | var  | value
1    | 01/05/2017 20:57 | Temp | 22   
1    | 01/05/2017 20:57 | Mode | Follow
2    | 01/05/2017 20:57 | Temp | 20
2    | 01/05/2017 20:57 | Mode | Override
1    | 01/05/2017 21:37 | Temp | 22*   
1    | 01/05/2017 21:37 | Mode | Follow*
2    | 01/05/2017 21:37 | Temp | 20*
2    | 01/05/2017 21:37 | Mode | Override*
1    | 01/05/2017 22:00 | Temp | 22*   
1    | 01/05/2017 22:00 | Mode | Follow*
2    | 01/05/2017 22:00 | Temp | 20*
2    | 01/05/2017 22:00 | Mode | Override*
1    | 01/05/2017 22:10 | Temp | 22*   
1    | 01/05/2017 22:10 | Mode | Follow*
2    | 01/05/2017 22:10 | Temp | 24
2    | 01/05/2017 22:10 | Mode | Override
1    | 01/05/2017 22:13 | Temp | 20   
1    | 01/05/2017 22:13 | Mode | Follow
2    | 01/05/2017 22:13 | Temp | 22
2    | 01/05/2017 22:13 | Mode | Override
```

Sequential duplicates would be removed to leave a dataset like:

```
zone | datetime         | var  | value
1    | 01/05/2017 20:57 | Temp | 22   
1    | 01/05/2017 20:57 | Mode | Follow
2    | 01/05/2017 20:57 | Temp | 20
2    | 01/05/2017 20:57 | Mode | Override
2    | 01/05/2017 22:10 | Temp | 24
2    | 01/05/2017 22:10 | Mode | Override
1    | 01/05/2017 22:13 | Temp | 20   
1    | 01/05/2017 22:13 | Mode | Follow
2    | 01/05/2017 22:13 | Temp | 22
2    | 01/05/2017 22:13 | Mode | Override
```

I'm stuck as to how to approach this... Perhaps the two connected rows can be melted into one row?

Comment: Are you looking for `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['zone', 'var', 'value'])`?

Comment: Great idea - will try it out! Hadn't come across the subset function